# Xcode 6.4 Entitlement bug

Tags: ios, xcode, entitlements

I just copied a project to a new VM running Xcode 6.4

There are two errors (with Fixes) that appear

> GameCenter: "Add the Game Center entitlement to your App Id"
>
> In-App Purchase: "Add the In-app purchase entitlement to your App Id".

This doesn't make sense because I already did this and everything was working on my old machine. These errors appeared when I copied my project to the VM.

I clicked "Fix Issue", and it added entitlement for Game Center.

But when I click "Fix Issue" for the In-App Purchase entitlement, it fixes the In-App Purchase entitlement problem, but the Game Center appears again!

When I click "Fix Issue" for the Game Center problem, it fixes Game Center, but then cause the In-App Purchase entitlement problem to appear!

I have no idea how to work around this! Everything was working fine on my old machine, and all I did was copy from the project from a backup to a new VM. There have been no code changes / file changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug had something to do with opening a project created with a previous version of Xcode.

I fixed it by creating a new project and just copying / Addding all my files again. Didn't have to get any new certs or anything.

Comment: yes, this fixed my project the first time. Now I got into it again somehow. is there a simpler fix?

Comment: I haven't encountered the bug recently - perhaps try installing an older version of Xcode, or updating to a newer version where it may be fixed ?

Comment: the client requires to use xCode 6.4. xCode works in mysterious ways, yesterday I fixed it by manually deleting all the provisioning profiles, downloading them again and setting signing identity to Don't Sign. I spent an hour on trying out random things and finally got it going. It sucks.

Answer (score 0):

You need request and add 2 new certificates (iOS development and iOS distribution) for new device.
So I dealt with this bug.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add the Game Center entitlement to your app.

I was having the same issue, the reason was i was using team provisioning profile. Make specific development profile with your app specific bundle id and this error will be gone.

I hope this will help someone.